# Statement.getGeneratedKeys() method

Tags: java

I'm currently watching a video tutorial, and I am really confused with this code:

```
public static boolean insert(Member mbr) throws Exception {

    String SQL = "INSERT INTO test (first_name, last_name) " +
                "VALUES (?, ?)";
    ResultSet keys = null;
    try (
            Connection con = DBUtil.getConnection(DBType.MYSQL);
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(SQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ) {

        stmt.setString(1, mbr.getFname());
        stmt.setString(2,  mbr.getLname());
        int affected = stmt.executeUpdate();

        if (affected == 1) {
            keys = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
            keys.next();
            int newKey = keys.getInt(1);
            mbr.setMemberid(newKey);
        } else {
            System.err.println("No rows affected");
            return false;
        } 
    } finally {
        if (keys != null) keys.close();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Regarding the `stmt.getGeneratedKeys()` method, since it returns the auto-generated key as a result of executing the Statement object, why does it need to invoke the `getInt()` method?

Also, the cursor, by default, is pointing before the inserted row so why is the `next()` method invoked before the `get.GeneratedKeys()`? Shouldn't the `next()` method be invoked first so that the cursor will go to the first result row before getting the `GeneratedKey`?

Comment: P.S. I tried changing the stmt.getGeneratedKeys() to stmt.getResultSet(), the input will be saved to the Database but it will give me an error: 

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at m.dgzmn.db.tables.MemberManager.insert(MemberManager.java:64)
 at m.dgzmn.db.Main.main(Main.java:22)"

Line 64 points to "keys.next()"
Line 22 points to "boolean result  = MemberManager.insert(mbr)" which is the call to this class's insert method. 

So there might be something with the getGeneratedKeys() which I don't know, this is really kind of confusing.

Answer (score 5):

Two things.  Some databases can return multiple generated keys per row, and they do not have to be integers, they could be a GUID string or something else.  Therefore, you need to call `getInt(1)` in the code above.  Second, you are incorrect, a ResultSet returned by JDBC is positioned *before* the first row, thus the need to call next().  If a ResultSet has no rows, calling next() returns `false` indicating there are no results.

Comment: getGeneratedKeys() return a ResultSet Object with the auto-generated key, isn't there a method to get it from the ResultSet other than the getInt()? I mean what's the use of having to return a ResultSet object with the generatedKey if you still need to invoke getInt()? You can just normally return a typical ResultSet then invoke the .next() then getInt(), right?

If the position of the ResultSet is before the first row then why is the getGeneratedKeys() invoke before the .next()? Shouldn't the .next() be invoked first to move the position to the first row before you invoke the getGeneratedKeys

Comment: It is actually technically possible for a query to return *both* a ResultSet (from the query) *and* generated keys.  That is why there are two separate methods.  Queries can also return [mutiple](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/tjvjdmlt.htm) ResultSets, therefore there is a getMoreResults() method.